# reach a HTML element using javascript without getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to javascript. I created this div called colorme. I can successfully color it via javascript. Now assuming i want to change the background of `<p>...</p>`, or `<span>`,etc how do i reach it via Javascript? (no jquery).

Like document.getElementById() would work on the div and i reach it. Now i cannot keep giving unique id's to all the elements. How do i reach the inner elements like `<p>` or `<span>`, etc?

```
<div id="colorme">
  <p>Blah Vblah Blah Content</p>
  <span>Blah Vblah Blah Content</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the element that you've found as a context for `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var colorme = document.getElementById('colorme'),
    spans = colorme.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

Note that `spans` is a NodeList -- similar to an array -- containing all the `span` elements within `colorme`. If you want the first one (indeed, the only one in your code sample), use `spans[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the many DOM traversal functions provided in standard javascript.

Tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node

and http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element

Answer (score 3):

Here are three ways:

1. If you only care about decent browsers, `document.querySelector` (returns the first matching node) and `document.querySelectorAll` (returns a NodeList) - e.g. `document.querySelector('#colorme p')`.
2. `HTMLElement.getElementsByTagName()` (returns a NodeList) - e.g. `document.getElementById('colorme').getElementsByTagName('p')[0]`
3. `HTMLElement.children`, etc. - `document.getElementById('colorme').children[0]` (`.firstChild` will probably be a text node, lots of fun DOM stuff to get into there, the quirksmode DOM intro linked to is good stuff).

Answer (score 2):

Although the answers do give good ways to do it for this specific case....

The issue you're facing is called **DOM-traversal**. As you know, the DOM is a tree, and you can actually traverse the tree without knowing in advance the element id/type/whatever.

The basics are as follows

- `el.childNodes` to access a list of children
- `el.parentNode` to access the parent element
- `nextSibling` and `previousSibling` for next and previous sibling nodes

For further info, see [MDC DOM pages](

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: getElementsByTagName()?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getElementsByTagName()`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the children:

```
var div = document.getElementById('colorme');

var i, l, elem;

for (i = 0, l = div.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
    elem = div.childNodes[i];

    // Check that this node is an element
    if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
        elem.style.color = randomColorGenerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in newer browsers you can loop through `div.children` instead of having to check the `nodeType`. The `children` collection contains only `Element` objects, whereas `childNodes` contains all node types (elements, text nodes, comments nodes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use:

```
var colormeDiv = document.getElementById('colorme');

var e1 = colormeDiv.getElementsByTagName('p');

var e2 = colormeDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

to get the two elements inside *'colorme'* div.

Answer (score 0):

getElementById is just one of JavaScript's DOM methods. It returns an HTMLElement DOM object which you can then query to find child, parent and sibling elements. You could use this to traverse your HTML and find the elements you need. Here's a [reference for the JavaScript DOM HTMLObject](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).

Answer (score -1):

[after answering, I realised this is no answer to your fully explained question, but it is the answer to the question raised in the title of your post!]

One nice way of doing this is declaring a global var on the top of your Javascript that refers to the document, which can then be used everywhere (in every function):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // set a global var to acces the elements in the HTML document
    var doc = this;

    function testIt()
    {
        doc.blaat.innerHTML = 'It works!!';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blaat">Will this ever work..?!</div>
    <button onclick="testIt()">Click me and you'll see!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As my first impression when I got to 'getElemenyById()' was that it sounds like a function that will iterate through the DOM's element list until it finds the element you need; this must take some time. With the above example, you simply access the element directly.
I'm not sure if I'm really saving CPU / adding speed this way, but at least it feels that way :)

Comment: The user want to reach elements without ID pointing. Your solution is like the getElementById function because you need to know the id. Futhermore, you should use getElementById instead of your solution. In summary, out of scope.